# Using React hooks, how to update the state of part of an object in an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

If I have the following state using React hooks:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
        {
            user: "Bob",
            cost: 25,
        },
{
            user: "Paul",
            cost: 30,
        },
    ])
```

I can map over the state like so:

```
{users.map((user, index) => (
                                <div key={index}>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            value={user.user}
                                            name="user"
                                            onChange={handleFoo(index)}
                                        />
                                        <input
                                            type="number"
                                            value={user.cost}
                                            name="cost"
                                            onChange={handleFoo(index)}
                                        />


                                </div>
                            ))}
```

Yet I am struggling to update the state when only one input is edited.

```
const handleFoo = index => e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        let newArr = [...users]
        newArr[index] = {[name]: value }
        setUsers(newArr)
    }
```

The above semi works, but it only updates one parameter. Using the above the state would be updated as per below (for example)

```
[
        {
            user: "Bob",
            cost: 25,
        },
{
            cost: 30,
        },
    ]
```

How can i spread the [index] and only update the section I need?

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to make use of the spread syntax to copy the old user before adding the updated property:

```
newArr[index] = {
 ...users[index],
 [name]: value 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For ref the code is/was 
newArr[index] = {
            ...users[index],
            [name]: value,
        }

        setUsers(newArr)